# Mongodb: write results unavailable from shard01... caused by.. sharded connection pool: connect failed

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, amazon-ec2, performance-testing

**Environment**

1. mongo db 2.6.3
2. CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
3. Java 1.7
4. Tomcat 7
5. Jmeter 2.11
6. Amazon ec2

Our mongo dbs are hosted in amazon ec2.
We have set up our servers based on the [recommended production architecture](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/) and is as  follows:

- 3 config servers
- 2 mongos running along with tomcats
- 2 mongod, which is a replica set with a primary and a secondary (shard 1)

We are currently load testing our application with 3500 concurrent users. Our application is messaging(write) heavy so we are currently experimenting with 2 dbs one for users and other for messages.
When we had single db(users, messages as collections) the avg response time was 2.3 seconds but the error rate is almost 0.00%.
When we had 2 dbs one with users and other with messages the avg response time was 1.1 secs, but the error rate has gone higher (0.16%)

When we checked the tomcat(app server logs) we found lots errors like the following:

~ 88% of errors:

```
 { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "write results unavailable from shard01-primary.mycompanys.com:27018 :: caused by :: Location13328 sharded connection pool: connect failed shard01-primary.mycompanys.com:27018 : couldn't connect to server shard01-primary.mycompanys.com:27018 (10.0.1.111), connection attempt failed" , "code" : 83}
```

~5.5% of errors:

```
ReplicaSetMonitor no master found for set: shard01
```

~2.2% of errors:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "could not contact primary for replica set shard01" , "code" : 7}
```

But the primary of the replicas (shard01-primary.mycompanys.com) was running while the errors were thrown.

```
shard01:PRIMARY> rs.status()
    {
        "set" : "shard01",
        "date" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:57:59Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [
            {
                "_id" : 0,
                "name" : "shard01-primary.mycompanys.com:27018",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 1,
                "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                "uptime" : 1032189,
                "optime" : Timestamp(1406913104, 6),
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-08-01T17:11:44Z"),
                "electionTime" : Timestamp(1406110686, 1),
                "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-07-23T10:18:06Z"),
                "self" : true
            },
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "name" : "shard01-secondary.mycompanys.com:27018",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 2,
                "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                "uptime" : 1032005,
                "optime" : Timestamp(1406913104, 6),
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-08-01T17:11:44Z"),
                "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:57:57Z"),
                "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:57:57Z"),
                "pingMs" : 0,
                "syncingTo" : "shard01-primary.mycompanys.com:27018"
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
    }
```

The connection pool settings are as follows:

```
db.connections.max=5000
db.connections.min=5000
```

Any pointers on fixing the errors are appreciated.

**Updated For answering Markus**

> You have a two member replica set?

Yes, we have a 2 member replica set (primary, secondary). It is our shard01.

> Do you use MMS monitoring?

Yes we do. But we can provide you the sh.status()

```
mongos> sh.status({verbose:true})
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("53cf92e43476cd1989296134")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard01-sh",  "host" : "shard01/shard01-primary.mycompanys.com:27018,shard01-secondary.mycompanys.com:27018" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "my_app",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard01-sh" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard01-sh" }
    {  "_id" : "my_app_load1",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard01-sh" }
        my_app_load1.users
            shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard01-sh  13
            { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("119de91b3e18488b70e497a0") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 1) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("119de91b3e18488b70e497a0") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("26b5524ea883044d602a56f0") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 17) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("26b5524ea883044d602a56f0") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("3c2659b4eb7ae237566420e4") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 18) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("3c2659b4eb7ae237566420e4") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("5b4be31feb7ae97c1e42e0e4") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 13) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5b4be31feb7ae97c1e42e0e4") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("6af6d205a883028e0c17d6f0") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 23) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("6af6d205a883028e0c17d6f0") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("7c2752cbeb7aefbc1ff6f0e4") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 24) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("7c2752cbeb7aefbc1ff6f0e4") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("954759cceb7aea12f666f0e4") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 15) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("954759cceb7aea12f666f0e4") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("b1de2d00eb7ae972f93180e4") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 16) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("b1de2d00eb7ae972f93180e4") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("c3d81bbca8830722302a5420") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 21) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("c3d81bbca8830722302a5420") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("d642db1ac29660293b70e497") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 22) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("d642db1ac29660293b70e497") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("e8afdf84a883072ba6e88420") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 19) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("e8afdf84a883072ba6e88420") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("fd1771c93e1847d350e497a0") } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 20) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("fd1771c93e1847d350e497a0") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 4) 
    {  "_id" : "my_app_inbox_load1",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard01-sh" }
        my_app_inbox_load1.inbox
            shard key: { "receiver_id" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard01-sh  20
            { "receiver_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "receiver_id" : "0003fd94eb7aed675be420e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 17) 
            { "receiver_id" : "0003fd94eb7aed675be420e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "154b48b2eb7ae977588b70e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 19) 
            { "receiver_id" : "154b48b2eb7ae977588b70e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "26022e7eeb7aefb6ea5ac0e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 23) 
            { "receiver_id" : "26022e7eeb7aefb6ea5ac0e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "37f8d531c296675666f0e497" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 24) 
            { "receiver_id" : "37f8d531c296675666f0e497" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "41bcd983a883072cd2fc96f0" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 37) 
            { "receiver_id" : "41bcd983a883072cd2fc96f0" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "4cfd5606eb7aecd6ed2420e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 38) 
            { "receiver_id" : "4cfd5606eb7aecd6ed2420e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "622680c0eb7aecd6e88ac0e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 21) 
            { "receiver_id" : "622680c0eb7aecd6e88ac0e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "6df5ff8aeb7aea143936f0e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 25) 
            { "receiver_id" : "6df5ff8aeb7aea143936f0e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "80aabb00eb7ae237593590e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 26) 
            { "receiver_id" : "80aabb00eb7ae237593590e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "8ad740cbeb7aecddaff590e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 33) 
            { "receiver_id" : "8ad740cbeb7aecddaff590e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "95e04ae3eb7aecd58be6f0e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 34) 
            { "receiver_id" : "95e04ae3eb7aecd58be6f0e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "9fd32b25eb7aeba6ea5030e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 31) 
            { "receiver_id" : "9fd32b25eb7aeba6ea5030e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "b05d1766eb7aecd7588590e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 32) 
            { "receiver_id" : "b05d1766eb7aecd7588590e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "bab06fdfeb7ae8c587dac0e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 29) 
            { "receiver_id" : "bab06fdfeb7ae8c587dac0e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "c8dbfa5feb7aee075be590e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 30) 
            { "receiver_id" : "c8dbfa5feb7aee075be590e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "d4471acdeb7ae8c4388420e4" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 27) 
            { "receiver_id" : "d4471acdeb7ae8c4388420e4" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "e53cf32d3e184ff180e497a0" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 28) 
            { "receiver_id" : "e53cf32d3e184ff180e497a0" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "eecfd315a88305f2375ff6f0" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 35) 
            { "receiver_id" : "eecfd315a88305f2375ff6f0" } -->> { "receiver_id" : "ffd9ee77c296619a52e0e497" } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 36) 
            { "receiver_id" : "ffd9ee77c296619a52e0e497" } -->> { "receiver_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard01-sh Timestamp(1, 4)
```

> Timeframe?

It happened somewhere in the middle of the test run. We have ran 2 runs of the same test but they produce the same sort of error rate. We have just cleaned the data inbetween the runs so the sharding and chuncks would have already been existing(created by the first run) by the time the second run happened.

Comment: A few questions: You have a two member replica set? Do you use MMS monitoring? Or can you at least provide us with the output sh.status()? Please also give the precise time frame in which the load tests were conducted and the times of the occurrences of such errors.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have answered your queries by updating the question. I can provide you with more information on the time frame, by re-running the tests, if the above information isn't sufficient.

Comment: I need the exact timeframe, that is start time and end time of tests to correlate that with your status and the election.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok first a few things.

#### Your replica set setup

It is a Very Bad Idea™ to run a two member replica set. You should at least have two data bearing nodes and an arbiter running. The reason for that is that an election always needs a majority. So if one of your nodes fails, there isn't a majority for an election (one of two isn't a majority), so no new primary can be elected. Actually, you made the situation worse than better in terms of availability, as you doubled the chances for one machine failing and putting the cluster into a state where nothing can be written. Please see   [the introduction into replication in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/#replication-in-mongodb).

#### Your shard key

You have made another very bad decision: Using the ObjectId as your shard key. Sharding is based on key ranges. As you can see in the output of `sh.status()`, there is a range from `$minKey` to a value, some ranges with values and last but not least one range from a value to `$maxKey`. Since the ObjectId is monotonically increasing, all new documents will be written to the shard which has this value assigned, instead of the documents be equally distributed among the shards. The balancer *will* take care of that problem, but chunk migration is pretty slow and you are overloading one shard. That problem doesn't hurt you yet, since you only have one shard, but you will notice pretty quick when you add a new shard. Please have a deep look into [Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) in the MongoDB docs.

#### Your sizing

When holding 5000 connections, that would use roughly 5GB of physical RAM, since each connection is assigned 1MB. Depending on your hardware setup, you will run into problems when your index size increases. MongoDB drastically looses performance when the indices can not be kept in RAM. We are talking of several orders of magnitude here. Instead of using such a high number of connections ( I assume you want to assign one connection per concurrent user) you should rather use a connection pool of reusable connections. On the sizing: the connection pool should be equal to the number of executor threads of your Tomcat installation. The default size is 200 as of the time of this writing. Since one thread will not be able to use more than 1 connection anyway, it is safe to say that your connection pool should have a size of 200 *per Tomcat instance* (as opposed to per application running on that instance). Adjust your values accordingly, as you won't likely be able to handle 3500 users with just 200 threads.

#### What happened?

Since I do not have the exact time frame of your tests, I can only make an educated guess what happened. Most likely, your replica set members are too small and you overloaded your primary up to the point that it didn't reply to the secondaries heartbeat request. In this case, the secondary would declare the primary dead after a while and would try to initiate an election. This election ends with a tie (one of two isn't a majority), so the secondary stays secondary. But since the MongoDB drivers and the sharded cluster are aware of replica sets, both will know that there was an election and that by tie, there was no primary elected for the replica set during the last election he knows of. It does not matter that the primary is still running, as it might well have been too overloaded to take part in the election (not answering to a heartbeat because of overloading was the reason the election was held in the first place).

#### What to do to verify?

1. Have a look into the log files of the secondary and try to find out wether an election was held during your load tests.
2. Have a deep look into the MMS statistics for the primary. I'd strongly assume that you will see high lock percentage and over proportionally many page faults correlating to the number of opcounters during the tests
3. Try to find out wethe your load tests were run around ISODate("2014-07-23T10:18:06Z"). This is more of a maybe, but worth a shot.

#### What to do to resolve the problem?

1. Read my notes above, including the linked documentation
2. Rinse and repeat ;)
3. Run at least an arbiter. I usually do not suggest that, since when you have to shut down one of the data bearing replica set members for maintenance or backup, you loose failover capabilities. In a sharded environment, I'd always suggest do deploy *at lease* 3 data bearing nodes *plus* 2 arbiters for a replica set, in case one data bearing node goes down unexpectedly during a maintenance operation on an other data bearing node. Arbiters are very cheap in terms of resources, and running them on a config server is ok. Just always make sure you have an odd number of voting nodes.
4. Choose a proper shard key.
5. Add a shard or scale up the existing shard. CPU isn't much of a concern, RAM and mass storage latency is.

Comment: Firstly we will add the arbiter . While I was monitoring with mongostat, there where either lot of connections, high data transfer, lot of inserts, or all the above; were  happening whenever the error rates were higher. So obviously the primary was overwhelmed.

Comment: Our shard key is not the default one from the mongodb, rather its a custom one which has high cardinality. We have used custom hashing function which produces 12-byte hash out of the uuid we have. we have used `public ObjectId(byte[] b)` constructor for generating that.

Comment: We used 5000 connections, since we were running tests with 5000 CCU earlier. Now we will make sure that it is the same as that of # of threads in tomcat(s).

Comment: Still, no matter what you use to "salt" ObjectID, it gets a monotonically increasing counter at the end. And you don't need your custom hashing function in case your generate a hashed index with `db.yourColl.ensureIndex({_id:"hashed"})` and shard the collection with `sh.shardCollection("yourDb.yourColl":{"_id":"hashed"}). Regarding the connections: just make sure that the pool per tomcat is equal to maxThreads. Otherwise: Glad I could help.

Comment: We are not using salt to the ObjectId, rather we use unique_id(like email, phone_no) then we hash it to produce 12-bytes and then store it in the object_id. Also I learnt that `db.yourColl.ensureIndex({_id:"hashed"})` cannot be used for range based queries like `$in`. Since we are using `$in` in some of our queries, we opted for this custom hashed `ObjectId`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If it works for you. ;) However, using a replica sets failover for dealing with load peak is not a good idea. The replica set failover is meant as improving availability when hardware or network outages occur. Think of it as an insurance you pay instead of having to set up a 24/7 support for your cluster. Elections can take quite some time, but they are still faster than manual intervention. If your shard can't take the load, add another.

Comment: Thumbs up for your suggestion on the replica set. BTW adding arbiter has resolved this issue, so I have marked this as an answer. We are grateful for your valuable inputs!!