# Mongodb connection checkout is slow

Tags: mongodb, go

```
Driver: go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.13.1
Mongo Version: 7
Server language: Go1.21
```

I have developed a app that listens to kafka messages and after collecting a batch/context time out pushes to MongoDB. I tested this app in local with local mongo server, all worked fine with a max mongo operation latency of `5ms`.

I use single client across application and after initiation using `mongo.Connect()` I ping the server `client.Ping()`

After deployement to cloud(AWS EKS+Mongo Atlas) each mongodb operation takes a additional 2s. To debug I enabled mongo log and pool monitor logs and noticed the following messages after I called `Find()` function

PFB for the code use to create the client

```
    connectionOptions := options.Client()
    connectionOptions.ApplyURI(c.ConnectionString)
    connectionOptions.SetConnectTimeout(time.Minute)
    connectionOptions.SetMinPoolSize(c.MinConnectionPool) //10
    connectionOptions.SetMaxPoolSize(c.MaxConnectionPool) //50
    connectionOptions.SetMaxConnIdleTime(time.Minute * 5)
    connectionOptions.SetCompressors([]string{"snappy", "zlib", "zstd"})
    connectionOptions.SetMonitor(mongotrace.NewMonitor())
    mongoLogger := &MongoLogger{log: logger.NewResourceLogger("MongoInternalLog"), ctx: log.GetContextWithCorrelation(context.Background(), log.GetDefaultCorrelationParam("MongoInternal"))}
    connectionOptions.SetLoggerOptions(&options.LoggerOptions{
        ComponentLevels: map[options.LogComponent]options.LogLevel{
            options.LogComponentAll: options.LogLevelDebug,
        },
        Sink:              mongoLogger,
        MaxDocumentLength: 1024,
    })
    connectionOptions.SetPoolMonitor(&event.PoolMonitor{
        Event: mongoLogger.PoolEvent,
    })
    opts = utils.Prepend(opts, connectionOptions)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(ctx, "error creating mongo connection", err)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("mongo.New: error creating mongo connection: %w", err)
    }
    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(ctx, "error pinging mongo server", err)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("mongo.New: error pinging mongo server: %w", err)
    }
```

PFB for the full log

```
2024-02-07 13:11:20.039 {"long_message":null,"short_message":"DB call completed"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.039 {"long_message":{"type":"ConnectionCheckedIn","address":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","connectionId":1,"options":null,"reason":"","serviceId":null,"error":null},"short_message":"mongo pool event"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.039 {"long_message":["message","Connection checked in","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","driverConnectionId",1,"serverPort",1025],"short_message":"Connection checked in"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.039 {"long_message":["commandName","find","databaseName","SOME_DB_NAME","driverConnectionId",1,"message","Command succeeded","operationId",0,"requestId",1961,"serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","durationMS",2,"reply","{\"cursor\": {\"firstBatch\": [],\"id\": {\"$numberLong\":\"0\"},\"ns\": \"SOME_DB_NAME.SOME_COLL_NAME\"},\"ok\": {\"$numberDouble\":\"1.0\"},\"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\":{\"t\":1707291680,\"i\":4}},\"signature\": {\"hash\": {\"$binary\":{\"base64\":\"6sB7qA7UlJUnvLbKSHe5RYC3fuw=\",\"subType\":\"00\"}},\"keyId\": {\"$numberLong\":\"<<>>\"}}},\"operationTime\": {\"$timestamp\":{\"t\":1707291680,\"i\":4}}}","serverPort",1025,"serverConnectionId",207521],"short_message":"Command succeeded"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.036 {"long_message":["commandName","find","databaseName","SOME_DB_NAME","driverConnectionId",1,"message","Command started","operationId",0,"requestId",1961,"serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","command","{\"find\": \"SOME_COLL_NAME\",\"filter\": {\"isActive\": true},\"lsid\": {\"id\": {\"$binary\":{\"base64\":\"<<>>\",\"subType\":\"04\"}}},\"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\":{\"t\":1707291680,\"i\":4}},\"signature\": {\"hash\": {\"$binary\":{\"base64\":\"6sB7qA7UlJUnvLbKSHe5RYC3fuw=\",\"subType\":\"00\"}},\"keyId\": {\"$numberLong\":\"<<>>\"}}},\"$db\": \"SOME_DB_NAME\",\"$readPreference\": {\"mode\": \"secondaryPreferred\"}}","serverPort",1025,"serverConnectionId",207521],"short_message":"Command started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.036 {"long_message":{"type":"ConnectionCheckedOut","address":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","connectionId":1,"options":null,"reason":"","serviceId":null,"error":null},"short_message":"mongo pool event"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.035 {"long_message":["message","Connection checked out","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","driverConnectionId",1,"serverPort",1025],"short_message":"Connection checked out"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.035 {"long_message":{"type":"ConnectionReady","address":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","connectionId":1,"options":null,"reason":"","serviceId":null,"error":null},"short_message":"mongo pool event"}

2024-02-07 13:11:20.035 {"long_message":["message","Connection ready","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","driverConnectionId",1,"serverPort",1025],"short_message":"Connection ready"}

2024-02-07 13:11:19.975 {"long_message":["driverConnectionId",0,"message","Server heartbeat started","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","topologyId","65c3215b76f2f05f266bdc4a","serverConnectionId",204103,"serverPort",1025,"awaited",true],"short_message":"Server heartbeat started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:19.975 {"long_message":["driverConnectionId",0,"message","Server heartbeat started","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","topologyId","65c3215b76f2f05f266bdc4a","serverConnectionId",204103,"serverPort",1025,"awaited",true,"durationMS",10010,"reply",{"Addr":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","Arbiters":null,"AverageRTT":0,"AverageRTTSet":false,"Compression":["snappy","zlib","zstd"],"CanonicalAddr":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","ElectionID":"000000000000000000000000","HeartbeatInterval":0,"HelloOK":true,"Hosts":["<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1026","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024"],"IsCryptd":false,"LastError":null,"LastUpdateTime":"2024-02-07T07:41:19.975393897Z","LastWriteTime":"2024-02-07T07:41:19Z","MaxBatchCount":100000,"MaxDocumentSize":16777216,"MaxMessageSize":48000000,"Members":["<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1026","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027"],"Passives":["<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027"],"Passive":false,"Primary":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024","ReadOnly":false,"ServiceID":null,"SessionTimeoutMinutes":30,"SessionTimeoutMinutesPtr":30,"SetName":"atlas-6aw3ab-shard-0","SetVersion":35,"Tags":[{"Name":"region","Value":"AP_SOUTH_1"},{"Name":"workloadType","Value":"OPERATIONAL"},{"Name":"availabilityZone","Value":"aps1-az1"},{"Name":"nodeType","Value":"ELECTABLE"},{"Name":"provider","Value":"AWS"},{"Name":"diskState","Value":"READY"}],"TopologyVersion":{"ProcessID":"65beb254f66a3031addd0e11","Counter":4},"Kind":10,"WireVersion":{"Min":0,"Max":13}}],"short_message":"Server heartbeat started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:19.655 {"long_message":["driverConnectionId",0,"message","Server heartbeat started","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","topologyId","65c3215b76f2f05f266bdc4a","serverConnectionId",202936,"serverPort",1027,"awaited",true],"short_message":"Server heartbeat started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:19.654 {"long_message":["driverConnectionId",0,"message","Server heartbeat started","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","topologyId","65c3215b76f2f05f266bdc4a","serverConnectionId",202936,"serverPort",1027,"awaited",true,"durationMS",10009,"reply",{"Addr":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027","Arbiters":null,"AverageRTT":0,"AverageRTTSet":false,"Compression":["snappy","zlib","zstd"],"CanonicalAddr":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027","ElectionID":"000000000000000000000000","HeartbeatInterval":0,"HelloOK":true,"Hosts":["<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1026","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024"],"IsCryptd":false,"LastError":null,"LastUpdateTime":"2024-02-07T07:41:19.654877201Z","LastWriteTime":"2024-02-07T07:41:19Z","MaxBatchCount":100000,"MaxDocumentSize":16777216,"MaxMessageSize":48000000,"Members":["<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1026","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027"],"Passives":["<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027"],"Passive":true,"Primary":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024","ReadOnly":false,"ServiceID":null,"SessionTimeoutMinutes":30,"SessionTimeoutMinutesPtr":30,"SetName":"atlas-6aw3ab-shard-0","SetVersion":35,"Tags":[{"Name":"region","Value":"AP_SOUTH_1"},{"Name":"provider","Value":"AWS"},{"Name":"diskState","Value":"READY"},{"Name":"nodeType","Value":"ANALYTICS"},{"Name":"availabilityZone","Value":"aps1-az1"}],"TopologyVersion":{"ProcessID":"65beb41b8483d5517a76b09f","Counter":4},"Kind":10,"WireVersion":{"Min":0,"Max":13}}],"short_message":"Server heartbeat started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.034 {"long_message":{"type":"ConnectionCreated","address":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","connectionId":1,"options":null,"reason":"","serviceId":null,"error":null},"short_message":"mongo pool event"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.033 {"long_message":["message","Connection created","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","driverConnectionId",1,"serverPort",1025],"short_message":"Connection created"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.033 {"long_message":{"type":"ConnectionCheckOutStarted","address":"<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025","connectionId":0,"options":null,"reason":"","serviceId":null,"error":null},"short_message":"mongo pool event"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.033 {"long_message":["message","Connection checkout started","serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","serverPort",1025],"short_message":"Connection checkout started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.033 {"long_message":["selector","","operation","find","topologyDescription","Type: ReplicaSetWithPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025, Type: RSSecondary, State: Connected, Tag sets: region=AP_SOUTH_1,workloadType=OPERATIONAL,availabilityZone=aps1-az1,nodeType=ELECTABLE,provider=AWS,diskState=READY, Average RTT: 1.323328ms, Min RTT: 1.253353ms }, { Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1026, Type: RSSecondary, State: Connected, Tag sets: workloadType=OPERATIONAL,provider=AWS,availabilityZone=aps1-az3,region=AP_SOUTH_1,nodeType=ELECTABLE,diskState=READY, Average RTT: 1.041377ms, Min RTT: 971.188µs }, { Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027, Type: RSSecondary, State: Connected, Tag sets: region=AP_SOUTH_1,provider=AWS,diskState=READY,nodeType=ANALYTICS,availabilityZone=aps1-az1, Average RTT: 1.369299ms, Min RTT: 1.261464ms }, { Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024, Type: RSPrimary, State: Connected, Tag sets: nodeType=ELECTABLE,availabilityZone=aps1-az2,diskState=READY,provider=AWS,region=AP_SOUTH_1,workloadType=OPERATIONAL, Average RTT: 806.192µs, Min RTT: 743.374µs }, ]","operationId",1961,"serverHost","<<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net","serverPort",1025],"short_message":"Server selection succeeded"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.033 {"long_message":["selector","","operation","find","topologyDescription","Type: ReplicaSetWithPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1026, Type: RSSecondary, State: Connected, Tag sets: workloadType=OPERATIONAL,provider=AWS,availabilityZone=aps1-az3,region=AP_SOUTH_1,nodeType=ELECTABLE,diskState=READY, Average RTT: 1.041377ms, Min RTT: 971.188µs }, { Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1027, Type: RSSecondary, State: Connected, Tag sets: region=AP_SOUTH_1,provider=AWS,diskState=READY,nodeType=ANALYTICS,availabilityZone=aps1-az1, Average RTT: 1.369299ms, Min RTT: 1.261464ms }, { Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1024, Type: RSPrimary, State: Connected, Tag sets: nodeType=ELECTABLE,availabilityZone=aps1-az2,diskState=READY,provider=AWS,region=AP_SOUTH_1,workloadType=OPERATIONAL, Average RTT: 806.192µs, Min RTT: 743.374µs }, { Addr: <<>>.<<>>.mongodb.net:1025, Type: RSSecondary, State: Connected, Tag sets: region=AP_SOUTH_1,workloadType=OPERATIONAL,availabilityZone=aps1-az1,nodeType=ELECTABLE,provider=AWS,diskState=READY, Average RTT: 1.323328ms, Min RTT: 1.253353ms }, ]","operationId",1961],"short_message":"Server selection started"}

2024-02-07 13:11:18.033 {"long_message":null,"short_message":"Making DB call"}
```

What is the root cause of this lag of 2s between `ConnectionCheckOutStarted` and `ConnectionCheckedOut` event and how to fix it?

Comment: Of the top of my head: write concern. Your replica set members live in two different AZs. While this is sound in general, this can take some time if your write concern is set to majority. Also, ***PLEASE*** have a look why having a two-member replica set is a Very Bad Idea™ in [one of my answers explaining it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141395/1296707) and [in the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb)